# Salesforce: Is it possible to add custom url to each row in the object overview page?

Tags: salesforce

I know it's possible to add the button on top of listview along with new button but is it possible to add custom button/link in each row? or I have to use the custom dynamic field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want something that's essentially a link to some other place - "custom link" would be the best solution, as @Jair has shown.

This however will display only on detail view pages and won't work if you want to see this link in places such as listview (on tab of the object) or in reports. To achieve this - make a new field. This field could be of type URL (if it has to be editable... or you might want to use some workflows to fill it in?).

Alternatively - if it doesn't have to be editable - make a new formula field (type = text) and then you can use functions like [`HYPERLINK()`](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_functions_a_h.htm&language=en_US#HYPERLINK) to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a new custom button/link, you can choose 'Detail Page Link' to implement it.

[image]